# Android Media Player did not open

Tags: android, itext, media-player

I am developing an android application that opens a PDF file and extract its content using itext then convert the results to an audio file using TTS engine and finally open the audio file using Media Player. 
The app works fine for me and I am able to view PDF files but I can't view the Media player. I need a way to view media player upon the PDF file like this [pdf_activity.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2TZX.png)
here is my code for PDF Activity:

```
public class PDF_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private double startTime = 0;
private double finalTime = 0;

private Handler myHandler = new Handler();;
private int forwardTime = 5000;
private int backwardTime = 5000;
private SeekBar seekbar;
private TextView tx1,tx2,tx3;

public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;

private TextToSpeech mTts;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

    //PDFVIEW SHALL DISPLAY OUR PDFS
    PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

    //UNPACK OUR DATA FROM INTENT
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    String path = i.getExtras().getString("PATH");

    //GET THE PDF FILE
    File file = new File(path);

    if (file.canRead()) {
        //LOAD IT
        pdfView.fromFile(file).defaultPage(1).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                Toast.makeText(PDF_Activity.this, String.valueOf(nbPages), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).load();

        try {
            String parsedText = "";
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int page = 0; page < n; page++) {
                parsedText = parsedText + PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, page + 1).trim() + "\n"; //Extracting the content from the different pages
            }
            reader.close();
            HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
            String destFileName = path.concat(".wav");
            myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, parsedText);
            mTts.synthesizeToFile(parsedText, myHashRender, destFileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String pdfMediaPalyer = path.concat(".wav");
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tx3.setText(file.getName());

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pdfMediaPalyer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekbar.setClickable(false);
    b2.setEnabled(false);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mediaPlayer.start();

            finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
                seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                oneTimeOnly = 1;
            }

            tx2.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)
                                    finalTime)))
            );

            tx1.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)
                                    startTime)))
            );

            seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
            myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime, 100);
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            b3.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = (int) startTime;

            if ((temp + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
                startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
                mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Jumped forward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = (int) startTime;

            if ((temp - backwardTime) > 0) {
                startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
                mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Jumped backward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot jump backward 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
    private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            tx1.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                    toMinutes((long) startTime)))
            );
            seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: So you have one class with one method with many responsibilities? Please refactor your code! At least put each separate responsibility in a separate method! How else are you ever going to test your code?

Comment: if i put media player method on background services , it will work ?

Comment: Is your question about IText? Does the iText part of your question work or not?